# How to mount Windows CIFS in Linux server using PKI authentication?

Tags: linux, windows, cifs, key-authentication

I have a Windows File Share server and want to mount those CIFS in Linux server using PKI authentication. This is the command to mount Windows shares in Linux using username & password:

```
mount.cifs //HPSERVER/WindowsFS-bup/ /home/maxg/bmsOnSrvr --v -o user=linux,pass=****
```

Any idea or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SMB - the Windows File Share protocol - does not support PKI authentication directly, but does support Kerberos authentication.

So if the Windows File Share server is a member of an Active Directory domain, and you can arrange some way to use PKI authentication to get a Kerberos authentication ticket, you could use that (with the `sec=krb5` or `sec=krb5i` option for `mount.cifs`) to mount the share. This seems to be possible, but rather complicated.

The first step would be to use `pkinit` (packaged as `krb5-pkinit` in some distributions) to [get an initial Kerberos authentication ticket using PKI authentication](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.13/doc/admin/pkinit.html). Once the user running the `mount.cifs` command has a valid `krbtgt` ticket for the Windows domain, `mount.cifs` can automatically request a further `cifs/servername@DOMAIN.NAME` ticket when `sec=krb5[i]` mount option is used.

This looks like a reasonably detailed description of such a setup:
[Enable Smartcard Authentication Against Active Directory and generate TGT using PKINIT](https://scriptech.io/linux-enable-smartcard-authentication-against-active-directory-and-generate-tgt-using-pkinit/).

Comment: Thank you telcoM, your support is appreciated very much. My environment is now configured to accept PKI authentication. Here is the command, to mount the Windows shares(haven't run this command, my assumption is that it should allow domains users already authenticated to access their assigned directory from an application server).  
//mydomain/share /mnt/myshare smbfs rw,auto,multiuser,mfsymlinks,vers=3.1,sec=krb5,credentials=/root/creds 0 0